# How to update multiple records in a data frame with new values from a separate data frame by index in R

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, merge, row

I am trying to figure out how to update various records in `df1` column `A` with new values from `df2` column `A`. `df1` has 2141 column `A` observations with a unique ID in the`Index` column. `df2` has 268 updated column `A` values with their associated unique ID in the `Index` column. I tried using `merge()`, or even a simple for loop with an if statement with no luck, such as:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){
    if (df1$Index[i] == df2$Index[i]){
        df1$A[i] <- df2$A[1]
    }
}
```

A simplified example of my two data frames and what result I'm trying to achieve:

```
df1:
   Index  A
1      1 NA
2      2 NA
3      3 NA
4      4 NA
5      5 NA
6      6 NA
7      7 NA
8      8 NA
9      9 NA
10    10 NA
```

```
df2:
  Index  A
1     2 85
2     3 46
3     6 79
4     7 64
5    10 40
```

```
Updated df1:
   Index  A
1      1 NA
2      2 85
3      3 46
4      4 NA
5      5 NA
6      6 79
7      7 64
8      8 NA
9      9 NA
10    10 40
```

I have to believe this is simple, but I can't figure out how to update my main data frame. My search for ideas online keeps going back to the  `merge()` function or similar join functions. Thank you for any help or guidance.

Comment: It is certainly an approach worth exploring, though since I'm updating values based on unique ID, it seems the canonical method may not be entirely appropriate. I'm currently using the merge() function, but it's requiring more clean-up than I would hope (remove A.x, rename column A.y to A, and re-sort Index. Regardless, thank you for the tip - this is an interesting method I imagine will be very useful for similar use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df <- data.frame(Index = 1:10 , A = NA)
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    x <- which(i == df2$Index)
    y <- which(i == df1$Index)
    if(length(x) > 0) df$A[i] <- df2$A[x]
    else if(length(y) > 0) df$A[i] <- df1$A[y]
    else df$A[i] <- NA
    
}
```

- output

```
   Index  A
1      1 NA
2      2 85
3      3 46
4      4 NA
5      5 NA
6      6 79
7      7 64
8      8 NA
9      9 NA
10    10 40
```

Comment: This makes complete sense - thank you! This really helped remove a lot of extraneous and verbose code.

Answer (score 0):

In dplyr you can do:

```
df2 %>% 
  full_join(df1) %>% 
  group_by(Index) %>% 
  filter(ifelse((length(row_number()) > 1) & is.na(A), 1, 2) == 2) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(-desc(Index))
```

Assuming that there is only a maximum of one unique Index value per df

```
# A tibble: 10 × 2
   Index     A
   <int> <int>
 1     1    NA
 2     2    85
 3     3    46
 4     4    NA
 5     5    NA
 6     6    79
 7     7    64
 8     8    NA
 9     9    NA
10    10    40
```

Comment: The filter(ifelse(...)) code is elegant! I've been doing this for just under a year, so this is all pure gold for me - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

These are the most 'simple' methods I could come up with; hopefully one of them will suit:

```r
df1 <- read.table(text = "  Index  A
1     1 NA
2     2 NA
3     3 NA
4     4 NA
5     5 NA", header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "  Index  A
1     2 85
2     3 46
3     6 79
4     7 64
5    10 40", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
full_join(df1, df2, by = "Index") %>%
  mutate(A = coalesce(A.x, A.y)) %>%
  select(Index, A)
#>   Index  A
#> 1     1 NA
#> 2     2 85
#> 3     3 46
#> 4     4 NA
#> 5     5 NA
#> 6     6 79
#> 7     7 64
#> 8    10 40

library(powerjoin)
power_full_join(df1, df2, by = "Index", 
                conflict = rw ~ ifelse(all(is.na(.x), is.na(.y)), 
                                       NA_integer_, 
                                       sum(.x, .y, na.rm = TRUE)))
#>   Index  A
#> 1     1 NA
#> 2     2 85
#> 3     3 46
#> 4     4 NA
#> 5     5 NA
#> 6     6 79
#> 7     7 64
#> 8    10 40

# Plyr method: note the order of dataframes is important
# this may not work on your 'real' data
library(plyr)
join(df2, df1, type = "full", by = "Index") %>%
  arrange(Index)
#>   Index  A
#> 1     1 NA
#> 2     2 85
#> 3     3 46
#> 4     4 NA
#> 5     5 NA
#> 6     6 79
#> 7     7 64
#> 8    10 40
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you - these are fantastic, very much appreciated.